# Trouble with filtering in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The problem that i am facing is as follows: If i were to select a particular tag/author from the Tags/Author dropdown, the results are getting narrowed down as expected; however, when i click the 'Clear' button, the content disappears. I have to refresh the page for all the results to be displayed again.

I have another application using the same logic and in that clicing the 'Clear' button does not lead to the results disappearing. So i'm a bit concerned as to why it's working in one instance and not in the other.

I'd appreciate if you can help me understand where i'm going wrong here.

The foll is a part of my filter logic:

```
<md-input-container>
<label>Enter Search Term</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="classifiedsFilter">
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
<label>Tags</label>
<md-select ng-model="tag">
<md-option ng-repeat="tag in tags | orderBy: 'toString()'" value="{{ tag }}"> <!-- tags here refers to a newly defined array that stores only one instance of all the tags against the 'tags' property on each object/word -->
{{ tag }} 
</md-option>
</md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

The foll are my filters on md-card:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="classified in classifieds | filter: classifiedsFilter | filter: tag:true | filter: expression | filter: book:true | filter: author:true | orderBy: order" flex-xs="100" flex-sm="40" flex-gt-sm="30" class="classified">
```

Comment: what is the code for Clear button? I think you are doing reset on tags array

Comment: @ashish the foll is the code for Clear button: `<md-input-container>
   <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="classifiedsFilter = ''; tag = ''; book = ''; author = ''; order = ''  ">Clear</md-button>
  </md-input-container>`

Comment: it would be more cleaner to move all assignments to a function in controller, and call that function in the html tag. And try assigning all the models to undefined/null.
Hopefully, that will solve the issue.. :)

Comment: @Nosail : Did it work ??

Comment: the problem is this logic works in a diff application, and it doesn't seem to work here. Also, i'm starting out with web dev so i'm afriad  i lack the skillset to implement your suggestion. but thanks for your help.

Comment: in your file: classified.ctr.js, inside your classifiedsCtrl

`$scope.clearFilters = function() {
 $scope.classifiedFilter = null;
 $scope.tag = null;
 $scope.book = null;
 $scope.author = null;
 $scope.order = null;
};`

and in your html:

`<md-input-container>
 <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="clearFilters()">Clear</md-button>
</md-input-container>`

Comment: @seekers01 thanks v much; i will refactor my code accordingly; but can you help me understand the rationale for this approach. how is this route better than the previous one? thanks

Comment: @Nosail: Did the change work for you ?? And its just a suggestion, you can choose to have all those assignment statements in HTML. But its much cleaner to keep less of javascript code in HTML files. calling a function instead, gives you a central place to look for any present or future issues ..